# How to fix for loop for a list

Tags: python, list, function, math

I am trying to create y as an array to create a function iterating through zeta which is dependent upon E all using a for loop.  However the values are not being added to the list.

I have also tried defining the variables and the mathematical function as two different coding functions

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlvLx.png)

```
import cmath

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 2*10**-15
Vo = 83*10**6
m = 1.6726*10**(-27)
pi = cmath.pi
E = []
E.append(-83*10**6)
hbar = 6.62607015*10**(-34)/ pi
K = 16.032280*10**6
y = []
y.append(51311.18131)

def variables(y, E):
    for i in range(1, 83, 1):
        alpha = cmath.sqrt(2*m*(E[i-1]+Vo)/(hbar**2))
        zeta = alpha*a
        eta = cmath.sqrt(k - zeta**2)
        y[i] = zeta*cmath.tan(zeta) - eta
        E[i] = E[i-1] + 1
    return y, E
print('E = ', E, 'Y = ', y)
plt.plot(E, y)
```

The program as of now should graph y values as a function of Zeta which is changing with energy.

Comment: You never call the `variables()` function.

Comment: You can't create new list elements by assigning to indexes, you have to use `append()`.

Comment: As noted you never actually *call* the function `variables()`. But furthermore I'll note that, the way you've written your code currently, there is no good reason to define a function anyways. Try working on getting your code working without the function definition first, and then you can worry later about generalizing it for further use if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop to be in a function, just put it at the top-level of the script. And use `y.append()` and `E.append()` to add to those lists.

```
for i in range(1, 83):
    alpha = cmath.sqrt(2*m*(E[i-1]+Vo)/(hbar**2))
    zeta = alpha*a
    eta = cmath.sqrt(k - zeta**2)
    y.append(zeta*cmath.tan(zeta) - eta)
    E.append(E[i-1] + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Barmar's answer your `k` variable needs to be `K` (upper case).

```
import cmath

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 2*10**-15
Vo = 83*10**6
m = 1.6726*10**(-27)
pi = cmath.pi
E = [0] * 83
E.append(-83*10**6)
hbar = 6.62607015*10**(-34)/ pi
K = 16.032280*10**6
y = [0] * 83
y.append(51311.18131)

for i in range(1, 83, 1):
    alpha = cmath.sqrt(2*m*(E[i-1]+Vo)/(hbar**2))
    zeta = alpha*a
    eta = cmath.sqrt(K - zeta**2)
    y[i] = zeta*cmath.tan(zeta) - eta
    E[i] = E[i-1] + 1

print('E = ', E, 'Y = ', y)
plt.plot(E, y)
```

Also it is not required to use `append` as sometimes `append` doesn't always work well with calculated index lookups. It might be better for you to initialize the `y` and `E` lists to be the length of your loop first.